# TJSONObject Memory Leak in complex json Object

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to serve a REST API service locally in a small business environment using idHTTPserver with Delphi Xe5. I pre process the file before sending it to the client, something is going wrong  at this point. The memory is not released after the process its completed.
The JSON Object created is sent correctly to the client after all (AngularJS App)

What am I doing wrong?

When I receive a HTTP Client request I do this..

```
Procedure TMain.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
Var
  // Here Var Types

  Json,LFilename:String;
  ROOTCOMANDAS,TORDEN,DATA,MSG : TJSONObject;
  Dlnew,d : TJSONArray
  files:tfilestream;

Begin

LFilename := ARequestInfo.Document;

if AnsiSameText(LFilename, '/resto/orders/jsondata') then
begin
  files := TFileStream.Create('htd' + LFilename, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyWrite);
  Json := ReadStringFromStream(files);
  files.Free;
  ROOTCOMANDAS := TJSONOBJECT.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Json), 0) as TJSONOBJECT;
  try
    Data := ROOTCOMANDAS.Get('data').JSONValue as TJSONOBJECT;
    d := Data.Get('d').JSONValue as TJSONArray;
    dlnew := TJSONArray.Create;

    for LValue in d do
      if (LValue as TJSONOBJECT).GetValue('ss').Value = '0' then
        dlnew.AddElement(LValue);

    TORDEN := TJSONOBJECT.Create;

    Msg := TJSONOBJECT.Create;
    Msg.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('t', TJSONString.Create('m5000_325')));
    Msg.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('tipo', TJSONNumber.Create(5)));

    TORDEN.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('msg', Msg));

    Msg := TJSONOBJECT.Create;

    Msg.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('et', TJSONString.Create(ETAGL)));
    Msg.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('d', dlnew));

    TORDEN.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('data', Msg));
    TORDEN.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('ok', TJSONTrue.Create));
    TORDEN.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('md', TJSONNumber.Create(iFD)));
    TORDEN.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('time', TJSONString.Create(UTC)));

    Json := TORDEN.ToString;

    AResponseInfo.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
    AResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] := 'Content-Type';
    AResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Allow-methods'] := 'GET,POST,OPTIONS';
    AResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Allow-origin'] := '*';
    AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
    AResponseInfo.Pragma := 'Public';
    AResponseInfo.Server := 'Drone';
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := Json;
  finally
    ROOTCOMANDAS.Free;
  end;

  exit;
end;
```

Comment: As far as I can see you are not releasing TORDEN variable anywhere

Comment: Yes .. because when i try to release that object i get Error, what i know when you release ROOTCOMANDAS or the Root Object you release the all Tree.. im right no?

Comment: Why don't you show the types of the variables you use? That could make a difference. Did you attempt to debug this? Full FastMM will tell you what has been leaked. Did you cut the code down until the leak disappeared? Learning these basic debugging skills will benefit everyone.

Comment: In  "d"  when i assign "For LValue in d do if (LValue as TJSONOBJECT).GetValue('ss').Value = '0' then dlnew.AddElement(LValue);"   If i destroy TORDEN and After ROOTCOMANDAS i get the same error , Null pointer blah blah,but the memory its not released

Comment: Cannot say for sure because I miss all the variable declarations, and cannot run Delphi right now, but I don't think you should be doing `dlnew.AddElement(LValue)`. What it looks like is that you are adding one owned object reference to another object that wants to own it too.

Comment: Your comment doesn't help. Please address our concerns with edits to the question.

Comment: TORDEN is TJSONOBJECT, ROOTCOMANDAS is TJSONOBJECT  i need do addelement in this case because i dont want to send all data stored in the Json Object just part of it thats why i use if sentence, then i build a new Json Object with less data than the json store on disk. But the problem here is when i call the service many times the program  increase the memory usage..

Comment: Wow!! refuse??? sorry if the solution is use FastMM and try to understand the issue, ok i go for that, i only add more comments in order to explain the error, i put code and almost identical in separate program and i get the same...then learning fastMM :( asap. thanks. Your Comment Refuse to help me  ;) ...

Comment: You have been repeatedly asked to **edit your question** and add all variable declarations.

Comment: `TORDEN` is not in the tree, so where is it released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never releasing `TORDEN` variable, hence the memory leak, and error you get when you do try to release it is caused by following lines:

```
for LValue in d do
  if (LValue as TJSONOBJECT).GetValue('ss').Value = '0' then
    dlnew.AddElement(LValue);
```

`LValue` is owned by `d` and will be released when `d` is released, and you are adding `LValue` to `dlnew` that will also want to release it. You have ownership issue here because two objects want to own and release same contained object.

Try following changes to solve the issue:

```
for LValue in d do
  if (LValue as TJSONOBJECT).GetValue('ss').Value = '0' then
    begin
      dlnew.AddElement(LValue);
      // here you are saying that you don't want to release object when ROOTCOMANDAS is released
      LValue.Owned := false;
    end;
// release ROOTCOMANDAS and d along with it
ROOTCOMANDAS.Free;
// Set back owned property to true so you don't leak objects
for LVaue in dlnew do
  LValue.Owned := true;
...
    Json := TORDEN.ToString;
    TORDEN.Free;

... remove superfluous ROOTCOMANDAS.Free; in finally part
```

Comment: THANKS YOU !! Dalija, seems to work right now.. i dont knew the use of "owned" method in TJSON objects of the DBXJSON library , Thanks a lot ... Javier.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may need this.
After many hours I found that this stops that nasty error:

```
procedure TForm1.DoEndDownload(const AsyncResult: IAsyncResult);
// happens after beginGet when sampledownload is invoked
var
isCan:boolean;
begin
...
       try
        isCan:= FAsyncResult.Cancel;  
        FAsyncResult.AsyncContext.Free;
       except
            on e:exception do
           //        memoMessages.Lines.Add('Cancelling Error: ' + e.Message);
       end;
...
end;
```

and SampleDownload  procedure includes this:

```
    URL := EditURL.Text+'/'+editTopic.Text+'/'+editParams.text;

     LResponse := FClient.Head(URL);
     LSize := LResponse.ContentLength;
     LResponse := nil;  // do not send a response because waiting for data

           FDownloadStream := TMemoryStream.Create();//(LFileName, fmCreate);


         // ---  Start the download/polling process  ----
        try
           FAsyncResult := FClient.BeginGet(DoEndDownload, URL, FDownloadStream);
            except
             on e:exception do
             log.Add('FClient BeginGet except: '+e.Message);
         end;
```

Please don't diss this solution because it works and while it may not help you it may help someone.